# Unable to print content of list in python

Tags: python

I've made a class containing a list, with the following  code:

```
class ProdReg:
def __init__(self):
    self.__Pliste=[]
```

This works perfectly.
I've also added a method to print the contents of my list:

```
def printProdReg(self):  
    for produkt in self.__Pliste:
        print(produkt)
```

This doesn't work all to great, When I try to add an object to this list, I get the following error:

```
<__main__.Bok object at 0x05777970>
```

The object is a class called `Bok`.

No idea what so ever how I can resolve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no problem, its just that the interpreter doesn't know how to print your object:

```
>>> class Me:
...     pass
... 
>>> me = Me()
>>> print me
<__main__.Me instance at 0xf98368>
```

If you need something to be printed, you can add an `__str__` method to your object:

```
>>> class Me:
...     def __str__(self):
...             return "It's Me!"
... 
>>> me = Me()
>>> print me
It's Me!
```

Answer (score 6):

The call to print calls [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) on your object, which by default prints the type and memory address. If you want a more readable representation of your object you need to give your class a new implementation of `__str__`.

```
class Bok(object):
     def __str__(self):
         return 'This is a Bok!'

     # Other members here...
```

Answer (score 2):

This actually is not an error - it's printing your object, which is of class Bok. Try adding `__str__` to the Bok class to print it's contents. You can see how here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Classes.

As a simple test, try adding this to your `Bok` class:

```
class Bok(object):
   def __str__(self):
      return "This is Bok"
```

and running your test again.

Comment: Tried to add you test, and that worked. I tried also to add the following: def __str__(self):
        return Produkt__str__(self)+' '+ str(self._produktForfatter) but this causes the follong error: NameError: global name 'Produkt__str__' is not defined

Comment: First, missing a dot - should be `Produkt.__str__`. Second, what is your goal when doing `Produkt.__str__(self)`?

Comment: To clarify, `__str__` in `Bok` class should only print what `Bok` object contains. If you have two variables `a` and `b` in class `Bok`, then your `__str__` method should be something like `return "a: %s, b: %s" % (a, b)".

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error, it's the object that is being returned by the function you're using to add to the list.